# Permissions not being inherited

Tags: windows, ntfs, file-server, permissions

So I have a parent folder `FolderA` which has:

```
Administrator FullControl Allow
FileAccessGroup FullControl Allow
TerminalServerDeny FullControl Deny
```

`FolderB` is a sub-folder with Inheritance enabled however `TerminalServerDeny FullControl Deny` is not being inherited (the others are), at least, not under the properties on the folder.

If I was to do an Effective Access test with a user in that group, it shows they have no access, however I cannot see it on the list when you go onto the Security Tab (not even in Advanced). How is this possible?

`FolderC` is working as it should, a sub folder like `FolderB`.

Comment: Can you provide screen shots?  And perhaps either a PS or CMD line output of the ACLs in the folders?

Comment: If you recreate `FolderA` with the permissions you want and copy the `FolderB` subfolder into it, does that fix the inheritance problem?  In my experience it's usually much quicker and easier to crate a new, working root folder than to worry about fixing a folder which isn't properly applying permissions for no ostensible reason.